# Arquillian + shrinkwrap-resolver: Unable to boostrap Aether repository system

Tags: java, maven, aether, shrinkwrap, jboss-arquillian

We have integration tests which are made with Arquillian. Shrinkwrap is used to resolve maven dependencies and build EAR file for tests. I just upgraded dependency of `org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver:shrinkwrap-resolver-bom` from 2.0.2 to 2.1.0 and got this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to boostrap Aether repository system. Make sure you're running Maven 3.1.0 or newer.
```

You can see the whole exception here: http://pastebin.com/rSbhCKEP

I tried Maven 3.1.1 and 3.2.1 with Java 1.7.0_51 - the result is still the same.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved after upgrading to Shrinkwrap 2.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

Probably this is the issue you are looking for:
https://issues.jboss.org/browse/SHRINKRES-174

UPDATE: I had the same issue and I resolved it by downgrading shrinkwrap again. So, probably we will need to wait for shrinkwrap 2.2 to go to final version :)